# Rails for ActionMailer - How to disable a Layout for a certain mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a user_mailer with a layout.

For one of my actionmailer methods I want the mailer to NOT use the default layout. But I can't see to find a setting for No Layout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply specify in your mailer:

```
layout false
```

You can also append `:only => my_action` (or `:except`) to limit the methods it applies to, like so:

```
layout false, :only => 'email_method_no_layout'
```

([applicable API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout))

Comment: Andrew, thanks but I want this for one mailer, not all. Where would this go when I have something like def XXX mail(:to => ....)   end

Comment: See updated answer. There is, always, more detail in the API as well.

Comment: unfortunately `layout 'my_layout', except: 'action'` does not work for me. I have to use `mail([…]) do |format| format.text {render layout: nil}} end` in the action.

Answer (score 5):

I did it by using a small function, looking at the action name and return the correct mailer layout to be used:

```
class TransactionMailer < ApplicationMailer

  layout :select_layout

  def confirmation_email contact
    #code
  end

  private
  def select_layout
    if action_name == 'confirmation_email'
      false
    else
      'mailer'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The layout method can accept the name of a method; use the method to determine whether to show a layout and return that name or false.

```
layout :choose_layout
...

private
def choose_layout
  if something
    return false
  else
    return 'application'
  end
end
```

Comment: How I can know what mail/method is going to executed?

Answer (score 3):

You could also be very sketchy and do this before the mail( ) call at the end of the specific mailer action instead:

```
@_action_has_layout = false
```