# How to disable a layout for a specific mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I need to be able to disable a certain layout for a specific email. I've taken a look at [Rails for ActionMailer - How to disable a Layout for a certain mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214738/rails-for-actionmailer-how-to-disable-a-layout-for-a-certain-mailer) however I don't know where to and how to output the code necessary. I'm new to Ruby and have searched the API documentation and can't find the exact line of code I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class YourMailer

  layout false, only: [:mail_method1, :mail_method2]

  def mail_method1
    #your code
  end
```

Comment: Do I put the colon before or after the only? Because for the other parameters (which are working), this is what it shows.
  default :from => "email@test.com"
  helper :application

Comment: `only: [` is the same as `:only => [`, just 1.9.2 ruby syntax

Answer (score -1):

You can be sketchy and simply do this before the mail( ) call:

```
@_action_has_layout = false
```